# Tomcat on DynDNS says "Connection Timed Out"

Tags: apache, tomcat, xampp, dyndns

I have a domain registered through DynDNS (dummydns.dyndns-server.com). I initially enabled port forwarding on port 80 for Apache-PHP and 8080 for Tomcat. I can access both on my local machine for Apache and Tomcat (localhost:80 and localhost:8080 respectively). However, I am only able to access Apache outside our network (dummydns.dyndns-server.com:80) but not Tomcat (dummydns.dyndns-server.com:8080). I figure I only need Tomcat for now so I swapped the two domains (now Apache is on 8080 and Tomcat on 80). To my dismay, I am still unable to access Tomcat (dummydns.dyndns-server.com:80) and still able to access Apache(dummydns.dyndns-server.com:8080).

So it's clear now that it is not a router issue but with server configuration.

I am running XAMPP 1.73 with Tomcat installed as add on. All configurations are defaults XAMPP configurations except for their ports (because I swapped them, no other config modifications).

Do I have to modify anything on Tomcat to enable remote access? Does it only allow local access by default?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does tomcat have any `Listen IP` configuration? `0.0.0.0` would say _Listen on all IPs_, `127.0.0.1` would say _Listen on localhost_. Maybe it has a `Listen Interface` configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the response. To tell you the truth, I have no idea. I am a LAMP guy and this is the first time I have to work on Tomcat.

Comment: @Jhourlad, look at [`address`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation), its description fits the bill.

Comment: I can't seem to find any entry on its config files that matches "address"

Comment: Do I have to put an entry to Apache's httpd.conf or does Tomcat have it's own virtual host file? And does it even have a significance on the issue?

Comment: silly me. it's a firewall issue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about that. It's a firewall problem.